# Ruby Regex: Rejecting selected URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, rubular

A survey software I'm using allows to exclude sites on which the survey should be shown using Ruby based Regex (they recommend testing strings on [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/)). I don't want to show the survey to clients that are close to finishing transaction, so excluding 3 phrases makes more sense to me than including all the rest.

How would I have to approach writing a ruby regex string that includes everything except phrases ***cart***, ***order*** and ***login*** within the URL?

Comment: regex's aren't very good at matches like "everything that doesn't contain a particular word".  But this question might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following *ruby code* rejects all strings in the array containing `cart`, `order` or `login`.

```
urls.reject { |url| url[/(cart|order|login)/] }
```

A raw regular expression which excludes words will use negative look-arounds:

```
^((?!login|order|cart).)*$
```

See [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/sXBoCeOcfg).

For more information, see @Max's suggested reading at [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

Comment: Rubular notified me of escaping forward slashes, which I added to your string, but then it still didnt match 1 of 4 testing URLs that didnt have any of the aforementioned phrases.

Comment: The forward slashes are the ruby syntax for regular expressions, much like quotes are for strings. Also, using `reject` _throws away_ any matching URLs, and _keeps_ only those which do not match.

Comment: Matt, please could you share the failing testing URL?

Comment: Sure, I'm still reading various materials regarding negative lookahead, but can't seem to write such a string. [Here is Uri's string with my testing URL's.](http://rubular.com/r/WTU5EGJm4H)

Comment: @Matt - we are having some misunderstanding - what I posted is _ruby code_, not a standalone regular expression. The raw regular expression is `(cart|order|login)`, which selects all the URLs which _contain_ cart,order or login.

Comment: That would explain a lot :) But still, I knew how to select phrases with OR statement, but can't figure out how to **exclude** them instead of including them. Is this possible at all?